# What is the purpose of the "probe server" button in administration UI?

Tags: tarantool

There is "expel server" button in the administration UI, which removes an instance from the cluster.
I thought that the "probe server" button recovers expelled servers, but it doesn't. What it's purpose?

Answer (score 1):

`Probe server` is needed to discover new unconfigured instances when they cannot be autodiscovered.
Unconfigured instance sends broadcast packets to the same port on the entire subnet, and to neighbour ports on the same machine;
Hence, if you start two instances on `<some_ip>:3301` and on `<some_ip>:3311` they will not discover each other, and you will need `Probe server`.